# The simplest way to generically traverse a tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, generics, abstract-syntax-tree, tree-traversal

Suppose I used `language-javascript` library to build AST in Haskell. The AST has nodes of different types, and each node can have fields of those different types.
And each type can have numerous constructors. (All the types instantiate `Data`, `Eq` and `Show`).

I would like to count each type's constructor occurrence in the tree. I could use `toConstr` to get the constructor, and ideally I'd make a `Tree -> [Constr]` function fisrt (then counting is easy).

There are different ways to do that. Obviously pattern matching is too verbose (imagine around 3 types with 9-28 constructors).

So I'd like to use a generic traversal, and I tried to find the solution in SYB library.

1. There is an `everywhere` function, which doesn't suit my needs since I don't need a `Tree -> Tree` transformation.
2. There is `gmapQ`, which seems suitable in terms of its type, but as it turns out it's not recursive.
3. The most viable option so far is `everywhereM`. It still does the useless transformation, but I can use a Writer to collect `toConstr` results. Still, this way doesn't really feel right.

Is there an alternative that will not perform a useless (for this task) transformation and still deliver the list of constructors? (The order of their appearance in the tree doesn't matter for now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it's the simplest, but:

```
> data T = L | B T T deriving Data
> everything (++) (const [] `extQ` (\x -> [toConstr (x::T)])) (B L (B (B L L) L))
[B,L,B,B,L,L,L]
```

Here `++` says how to combine the results from subterms.

`const []` is the base case for subterms who are not of type `T`. For those of type `T`, instead, we apply `\x -> [toConstr (x::T)]`.

If you have multiple tree types, you'll need to extend the query using

```
const [] `extQ` (handleType1) `extQ` (handleType2) `extQ` ...
```

This is needed to identify the types for which we want to take the constructors. If there are a lot of types, probably this can be made shorter in some way.

Note that the code above is not very efficient on large trees since using `++` in this way can lead to quadratic complexity. It would be better, performance wise, to return a `Data.Map.Map Constr Int`. (Even if we do need to define some `Ord Constr` for that)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll look into that and using a Map instead of a list. However, in your example the B constructor has only two fields. In my case, numerous constructors have different amount of fields. Does it matter in this case?

Comment: Also, could you please specify, which module's `everything` do you mean exactly? I tried a couple, neither have the type that matches with your example.

Comment: UPD: Looks like `Data.Generics.Schemes`, is that correct?

Comment: @IlyaChernov Correct.

Comment: Alright, I tested this approach against all the use cases I've got so far and it works perfectly. Thank you very much! Next I'll try to employ `Map` instead of lists, as you suggest

Answer (score 4):

[universe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Operations.html#v:universe) from the `Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data` module can give you a list of all the sub-trees of the same type. So using Ilya's example:

```hs
data T = L | B T T deriving (Data, Show)

tree :: T
tree = B L (B (B L L) L)
```

```hs
λ> import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data
λ> universe tree
[B L (B (B L L) L),L,B (B L L) L,B L L,L,L,L]
λ> fmap toConstr $ universe tree
[B,L,B,B,L,L,L]
```

Comment: This alternative is, of course, more concise. But will it work in my example, given that there are nodes of different types in my AST?

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, [`universeBi`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Operations.html#v:universeBi) could be used to get all values of a specific type inside a different type.

Comment: I think it is easier to demonstrate what I wanted to do with my current implementation of it: https://github.com/ch3rn0v/dry/commit/8f4ea0bcc14087adbc9aa2c2223de437fcb5553b (particularly `countConstructorOccurrences`)